# Why does iOS disables the animations?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I have a strange problem with my iOS Application for the iPad.

All animations are working fine. I use AQGridView for a nice looking gridview, works all great.. But all of a sudden my animations are gone. Like sliding when pressed in the navigationcontroller, now it's just there immediately. When I press a button which calls a method with a UIView beginAnimation block inside it, the animation part is skipped and the content just pops up with no animation at all...

When I quit the app, force it to quit in the multitasking part, and start the app again I have no problems anymore with the animations until the moment I press the AQGridView cell after x amount of times and the problem is back...

How is it possible the UI disables the animations? And how can I locate the problem?

Hope someone can help me with this one...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: verify that all your animations are in the main thread...

Comment: I call some animations with the performSelectorInBackground.. But why are the animations blocking at all and never come back untill I force quit the app....

Comment: Can you past the code you use when you press the AQGridView cell?

Comment: If you make an animation in background the behavior is undefined. So i recommend you to do all work in main thread ...

Comment: is this on the device, simulator, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make sure it's not something obvious, are you ever calling `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]`? Perhaps for some reason the code path you expect isn't followed and the corresponding `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]` doesn't run.

Comment: THX! Stupid stupid stupid.. AQGridView indeed does call setAnimationsEnabled to NO, and later set it to YES. But there was one method which uses a variable to set the animations. I forced it to be YES and now the animations stay alive :D Thx!!